# Android Progressbar по центру

Tags: android

необходимо на время загрузки данных вместо recyclerview поставить по центру progressbar круговой. Сейчас он находится выше RecyclerView, что не очень красиво. 
Как это можно сделать?

Разметка

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyTextView"
        android:text="No results found."
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните `LinearLayout` в `FrameLayout` и в него поместите ваш `ProgressBar` с `android:layout_gravity="center"`